# python selenium: close modal cookie from easyjet website

Tags: python, selenium

someone of you, can close the first modal on the website of flight company easyjet, accepting the cookie policy?

i tryed in many way but never closed it

this is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time
import os

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.easyjet.com/it")

time.sleep(2)

#chiudi cookie
cookie = driver.find_element(By.id,"ensCloseBanner")
cookie.click()
time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a typo. instead of `id` it should be `ID`

```
cookie = driver.find_element(By.ID,"ensCloseBanner")
```

Reference link : [Selenium python locator](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: yes, this is wrong, but also using ID not work... i don't know why

Comment: What error do you get? I tried it and the website loads like 'indefinitely'
Is it that the website loads infinitely and hence nothing happens after the `driver.get` is done? No issue when done manually though; in which case, I suspect that the website is detecting the bot action and hence tricking to load infinitely, thus not allowing any action to be performed.

Comment: no error receive, but i see not close the modal. So i don't know how is possible to continue. Sure someone make scraping on it because on some website there are this flights, they don't give the api.
There is a way for scrape it?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @KunduK, `id` should be `ID`.

Then, instead of using `.click()`, use `send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`.

```
cookie_button = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "ensCloseBanner")
cookie_button.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```